# How can we keep unique id, if me make primary key any other column

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, orm

I want to use default generation ID as well and make another field a primary key..
Can I do that with django ?.

**this is my object::**

```
{
    "platform_subscriber_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",#this is custom primary key.
    "platform_subscriber_entity": "loop",
    "platform_subscriber_secret_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "is_remove": false,
    "update_time": "2022-02-09T09:18:28.991032Z",
    "create_time": "2022-02-09T09:18:28.991038Z",
    "platform_subscriber_owner": 1
},
```

**i want old one unique ID too..**

```
{
        "id":1,#this is default one i want back
        "platform_subscriber_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",#this is custom primary key.
        "platform_subscriber_entity": "loop",
        "platform_subscriber_secret_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "is_remove": false,
        "update_time": "2022-02-09T09:18:28.991032Z",
        "create_time": "2022-02-09T09:18:28.991038Z",
        "platform_subscriber_owner": 1
    }
```

this is how my model looks like:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    platform_subscriber_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_("project owner"),db_column="platform_user_id", on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    platform_subscriber_id = models.CharField(_("Project Key"), db_column="platform_subscriber_key", max_length=64,primary_key=True, blank=True)
    platform_subscriber_entity = models.CharField(_("Project Names"), max_length=64,blank=True)
    platform_subscriber_secret_key = models.CharField(_("Project Secret Key"), max_length=64,blank=True)
    is_remove = models.BooleanField(_("Remove"),default=False)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(_("Updated Time"), default = timezone.now)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(_("Created Time"), default = timezone.now)
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Only single-column primary keys are supported. You can make it `unique=True` instead of `primary_key=True` would that solve your problem
[check this](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/models.html#:%7E:text=Do%20Django%20models%20support%20multiple,column%20primary%20keys%20are%20supported.)

But this isn’t an issue in practice, because there’s nothing stopping you from adding other constraints (using the unique_together model option or creating the constraint directly in your database), and enforcing the uniqueness at that level.